# Ants digging next to the root of my newly planted Japanese maple

Tags: ants, japanese-maple

Damn

It has been raining here every day and I have not had a look at my Coral Bark Japanese maple in a while
Today I had a look and I noticed ants digging their nest/galleries around the tree, some of these are darker because my wife "put some windex" on them (that is a joke but she used vinegar)

How do I get rig of these beasts? Is my tree in danger? 
The ants are small size not carpenter ants

[image]

the tree looks like this

[image]
[image]

During my research into this I came accross this thread http://forums.botanicalgarden.ubc.ca/threads/coral-bark-chlorosis-nutrient-deficiency-or-sun-burn.56911/ which shows a similar issue with aggravated symptoms for the tree. The opinions are split between Sun-Burn and Lack of fertilizer, many seem to be inclined toward sun burns

I have also cross checked about ants -it seems that they are not a problem, I guess they will go away as I will continue to water the tree daily every evening

Answer (score 1):

MiniMe...ants are not a problem ever for plants.  Well, they do the aphid harvesting gig but even then no problems really.  Was the bottom of this trunk buried for awhile?  How does the rest of your tree look?  I'd get rid of the straw for sure.  Don't worry about the ants.

Coral bark Japanese Maples are breath taking.  As long as your tree is healthy I don't see any problems.  I would clean out those weeds and hidey spaces for insects around the base of your tree.  If you have any problems it might be because of compromised bark at the bottom of your tree.  Interesting because this must have happened in a pot?  Before you planted here in this spot?  No more vinegar or 'windex'.  That could make the soil far too acid for any plant to thrive.  Windex...grins!  Ants and spiders are good guys.  That is all I have for macro organisms in my soil!  I just got a load of earthworms, sprinkled them around my 5 year old improved soil. They must have liked it because they disappeared by the time I finished!

Comment: see the pictures above, I have no idea if the tree is OK or no, looks quite reddish to me :-) ..if you check older posts around here from when I got the tree it was much greener then There are some dots/spots that can be noticed if you click on the last picture

Comment: yeah, this doesn't not look healthy.  Those leaves should be a bright...light or limeish green.  These look blanched?  Or is that the photo?  What have you fertilized with?

Comment: No fertilizer, that is pretty close to the real color. The plant takes full sun all the day long

Comment: You need to get some straight forward fertilizer.  There are tree spike fertilizers that last...well a long time.  Your tree is not able to produce enough of something to feed itself to then be able to maintain that green color.  Red is indicative not only of genetics but in coral bark leaves that red means stress.  No color is even more stress.   Too much fertilizer or no fertilizer are the two problems I've encountered with fertilizer.  Perhaps unbalanced fertilizer.  Do you fertilize your lawn?  Your tree loves acid your lawn loves more alkaline...

Comment: Without proper chemistry, photosynthesis can't happen.  The chemistry is as important as water and light and drainage.  Soils do not come with this chemistry, us humans have to add it with knowledge and discretion.  Good old Osmocote or tree spikes with balanced fertilizer will make a huge difference as long as the pH of your soil is appropriate.  Have you limed your lawn recently?

Comment: No, I have not done anything to my lawn since we moved here, not fertilizers at all (next year I will have to deal with the lawn I am reading that I need a  X-Y-Z where X=3*Y and Z does not matter. Am I correct ?

Comment: @MiniMe  Sorry,  all plants need a balanced fertilizer.  In your case for both your lawn and tree higher nitrogen in relation to P and K or Y and Z is fine.  Lawns need more nitrogen.  Trees and shrubs and perennials and vegetables that are grown for vegetative stuff need higher N in relation to P and K.  Lawns absolutely have to be fertilized.  Your tree has to have fertilizer.  Without fertilizer added by us humans your plants will not be able to do photosynthesis which is how they make their own food.

Comment: Lawns are very demanding because we cut them down.  And I am not into mulching at all.  Another story.  You should try Dr. Earth's Lawn Fertilizer!  Actually saves money per season.  Get a tree spike.  Only water your lawn when you are able to see your footprints on the grass stay down.  And water deeply!  Soaked.  This should suffice for your tree and shrubs and plant beds just fine.  Do you use automated irrigation?  Lawns need at least 4X per season of fertilizing, each formulation is based on the time of season.  Dr. Earth or similar will only require 3X maybe less.

Comment: ...only water again when you are able to see footprints on your lawn. That means the grass leaves have less turgidity to pop upright.  That is the perfect time to SOAK you lawn...and I do all at the same time.